# Maven: Show comment/alert in console when a dependency is used (compile/package/...)

Tags: maven, dependencies, alert

I need to be "warned" by Maven when I'm using an specific dependency, for example by showing an alert message on the console when compiling o packaging the project. I haven't found anything in the dependency pom.xml specs.

Thanks.

Comment: The questions is: Why do you need such thing or what's the purpose of this?

Comment: We have started recently to migrate our projects to Maven, and the first 'mavenized' version of a library (the dependency) requires a database field that old versions doesn't. When we package a new project that uses this new depency we had to be warned so we can tell our customers that they must create that database field. I hope I have explained myself (my english is not very good...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) to check for such dependency and break the build in such case. This might solve it halve a way but not 100%. May be you can write a [custom rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) to fulfill the need in this case.